# Is there anyway to start rsyslogd without sudo access?

Tags: docker, sudo, syslog, rsyslog

I'm running docker container without sudo access using

```
docker run -it --user 739000:8500 blabla...
```

Is there anyway I can start rsyslogd deamon inside this docker container without sudo access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to start rsyslogd inside docker container by modifying permissions of some relevant files, including pid file, config file and etc. when building a docker image. However, after such changes, rsyslogd can only be started once, and it can't get restarted, as /var/lock/subsys/rsyslog can't be removed without sudo. Is there anyway I can modify permission of /var/lock/subsys/rsyslog so that it can be removed without sudo?

Answer (score 0):

EVen from your Linux host, you can simply use [`docker logs --follow`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) to follow the logs from that container.
Or you can [run your container with a log driver configured](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/), allowing you to query the syslog of your Linux host directly (instead of the container itself)

Comment: Well. There is some management decision that I need run docker without sudo and we want to run rsyslogd inside docker container to forward logs. I actually managed to start rsyslogd in docker container without sudo by modifying permissions of some necessary files like pid and config files.

Comment: @kevinlu great! What sequence of commands did you use to start rsyslogd in docker container without sudo?